# MFC toolbar: How to set dropdown button width

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I am developing an MFC-based C++ application using Visual Studio 2010. There is a `CToolBarCtrl` with some dropdown buttons next to icons.

A user running Windows 8 has reported that they cannot see one of the icons in this toolbar. They provided a screenshot which shows that they are running Windows 8 at 150% UI zoom. My application is currently set to not be DPI-aware so this should actually not make a difference. (EDIT: apparently it does make a difference, after all - they no longer have the problem when switching to 96 DPI.)

As can be seen in the screenshots below, the toolbar dropdown buttons are much wider on their Windows installation than they should be. The spacing between the icons in the left toolbar is thus so big that the last icon cannot be seen anymore. The right toolbar in the screenshot (which does not have any dropdown buttons) appears as intended.

Mine (as it should be):

[image: Toolbar as I see it]

Theirs (dropdown buttons too wide):

[image: Toolbar as they see it]

My application already sets the icon (16x16) and button (27x24) sizes, but that obviously does not affect the dropdown button size.

So my question is: Why is it possible that the dropdown buttons can be wider than on my default Windows installation, and how can I change them to be the default size so that all icons fit into the toolbar? I didn't find any API that could actually set the toolbar dropdown button width.

Init code in my class derived from `CToolBarCtrl`:

```
SetButtonStructSize(sizeof(TBBUTTON));
SetBitmapSize(CSize(16, 16));
SetButtonSize(CSize(27, 24));

SetImageList(&icons);
SetDisabledImageList(&disabledIcons);

LONG lStyleOld = GetWindowLong(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
lStyleOld |= CCS_NORESIZE | CCS_NOPARENTALIGN | CCS_NODIVIDER | TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS | TBSTYLE_FLAT;
SetWindowLong(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE, lStyleOld);
```

Comment: Does this user have a touch input device attached to their machine? I seem to recall that Windows 8 did modify GUI element spacing when a touch display was detected.

Comment: Interesting thought! I'll get back at them, thought this will probably take a while since they haven't shown up in a while. Sadly I don't have any hardware to verify this by myself.

Comment: You might be able to test this without dedicated hardware. The [Input Simulator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff727737.aspx) installs a virtual touch digitizer device. This might be enough to change system behavior, if my assumption is correct.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot seem to get the Input Simulator to run on Windows 8 (which might not be a big surprise given that the SDK is only intended for Windows 7), and on my Windows 7 development machine the UI is not affected by the input simulator.

Comment: While I was not able to verify it myself, I got a reply from the user and they confirmed that they were indeed using a convertible, so that confirms your suspicion. Now the question remains if I can actually do anything against this resizing, as it effectively renders some icons unreachable.

Comment: @IInspectable: Your link is dead.